# Notifications for logged in and logged out users

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are 2 types of notifications that I want to send -

1. Notification for a logged in user
2. Notification for a user who is not logged in, aka, promotional notification

Here is how I am thinking to implement this -

1. Notification for a logged in user

- When the user logs in, frontend will generate the token and send it
  to the backend along with the device id
- When user logs out this token will be deleted from frontend local
  storage and request will be sent to backend to remove this token from
  the database
- When user logs in again, frontend will generate a new token and
  send it to the backend

2. Notification for a user who is not logged in, aka, promotional notification

- When app is opened for the first time frontend will generate token and send it to the backend
- When user logs out nothing needs to be done

**For 1 device there will be 1 logged in token and 1 promotional token**

To send notification to logged in user - find token for that user which has a device id
To send notification to user who is not logged in - find token for that user which does not have a device id

Is this how it should be done or is there a better way?

Comment: No, you can delete from your local shared preference but you cannot delete the device token instead you can check in onMessageReceived and check if the user is logged in or not with this implementation you don't have to send push notifications based on token you can simply push on topics

Answer (score 2):

You can set topic inside the app for user's who have not logged in yet. To do this, you can check Firebase official documentation. Here is the link how it is done for the group of devices [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple)

For logged in users, yes, you are right. You send a reqeust to login (to the server) after successful login, you send your push token to your server to use it when you want to send user-specific pushes via your server. After successful logout, you should remove that token from the server. However, it is not guaranteed, though